# Get notified by the time a new object is added to a NSArrayController

Tags: cocoa, key-value-observing, nsarraycontroller, nsnotification

I want to execute a method (or selector) every time a new object has been added to my array controller.

I guess it can be somehow done with key-value observing, but I don't exactly know how.

Can someone give me example code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Add yourself as an observer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/addObserver%3aforKeyPath%3aoptions%3acontext%3a) for the array controller's `arrangedObjects`. When an object is added or removed in its content array, it will add or remove it at the appropriate position in that array, and it will [notify any observers with the change](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/observeValueForKeyPath%3aofObject%3achange%3acontext%3a).

The dictionary describing the change will contain [keys that describe exactly what happened to the array](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSKeyValueObserving_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Keys_used_by_the_change_dictionary), so you can find the object that was added without having to look at any others.